# I would like my answer on Stack Overflow to no longer be deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I post [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179498), then it got deleted. I would like it undeleted. It's not spam; it answers the question.

The contents of the answer are as follows:

> I have made a PHP script which is designed to import large database dumps which have been generated by phpmyadmin or mysql dump (from cpanel) . It's called PETMI and you can download it here [[project page]](https://desbest.com/projects/petmi) [[gitlab page]](http://gitlab.com/desbest/petmi).

Comment: The answer is nothing more than a link to a off-site resource. This is a perfect reason for deleting it.

Comment: Note this will Meta question, too, will inevitably be closed as a duplicate of “your answer is in another castle”, and eventually deleted. Honestly, if you want to promote your own work, do it in your user profile.  SO is not a marketing platform.

Comment: answer undeleted since it looks much better now.

Answer (score 8):

To use most of what's useful about your answer, you'd need to follow the link. If the link died, where would we be then?

If you want your answer undeleted, you need to expand it so that it answers the question without the link—i.e., explain what your program does and how it works. Then your link would just be an addendum at the end, saying, essentially, "if you don't want to do all that yourself, here's an example solution".

Also, your answer does not describe how one would use your program to solve that user's problem. Are there specific command line options that would be needed? The answer is too generic to be a good answer to that particular question.

Comment: I'll expand on what my program does.

Comment: And more importantly describe how it works i.e. how would someone else go about writing that program.

Comment: Sorry, foiled by a low-quality laptop keyboard. That "m" was supposed to be a comma.

Comment: Done. I've updated my answer.